# I need to check my users if they exist in my database before i redirect to registration or normal Laravel registration

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a basic registration form with two fields to check my users if they exist, not exactly if they exist but I am checking for certain criteria, i am not sure how to modify my new controller to view the registration form which will then redirects to normal laravel registration

here is my controller script part of it:

```
Route::get ('/check','CheckUserController@view');
Route::resource('checkUser', 'CheckUserController');
Route::post ('/checkuser','CheckUserController@checkUser');
Route::get ('/failedRegistration','CheckUserController@view');

Route::get('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

and here is where I call if the user is successfully registered

```
 return view('register');
```

Comment: so the default auth flow that laravel ships with is not OK for you?

Comment: Code shown is not enough to know the issue. Please show some proper code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it finally, I just needed to change 
`return view('register');` 
to 
`return view('auth.register');`

and remove the routes for register coz its already known by laravel

Answer (score 0):

You Route Error

```
Route::get ('/check','CheckUserController@view');
Route::resource('checkUser', 'CheckUserController');
Route::post ('/checkuser','CheckUserController@checkUser');
Route::get ('/failedRegistration','CheckUserController@view');
Route::get('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Correct Route

```
Route::get ('/check','CheckUserController@view');
Route::post ('/checkuser','CheckUserController@checkUser');
Route::resource('checkUser', 'CheckUserController');
Route::get ('/failedRegistration','CheckUserController@view');
Route::get('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

First Route Post

```
 Route::post ('/checkuser','CheckUserController@checkUser');
```

Second Route resource

```
Route::resource('checkUser', 'CheckUserController');
```

Comment: I solved it finally, I just needed to change   return view('register'); to auth.register and remove the routes for register coz its already known by laravel